# How to run this Luigi Task- TaskClassNotFoundException(cls._missing_task_msg(name))

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to run 1 luigi task in command prompt named test.py and class named Test like this

```
luigi -m test Test --local-scheduler
```

How to pass parameter and run this in ubuntu

code sample:

```
class Test: 

    def requires(self):
        return class1(param1='path', param2='', param3=123)

    def run(self):
        # some logic with using those 3 params

    def output(self):
        pass

class Class1(luigi.Task):

    param1 = luigi.Parameter()
    fileparam = file
    param2 = luigi.Parameter(default=fileparam)
    param3 = luigi.Parameter(default=123)
```

but I am getting this error

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/luigi", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(luigi_run())
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/cmdline.py", line 11, in luigi_run
run_with_retcodes(argv)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/retcodes.py", line 69, in run_with_retcodes
with luigi.cmdline_parser.CmdlineParser.global_instance(argv):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/cmdline_parser.py", line 52, in global_instance
new_value = CmdlineParser(cmdline_args)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/cmdline_parser.py", line 76, in __init__
Register.get_task_cls(root_task)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/luigi/task_register.py", line 179, in get_task_cls
**raise TaskClassNotFoundException(cls._missing_task_msg(name))
luigi.task_register.TaskClassNotFoundException: No task Test.** Candidates are: Config,ExternalTask,RangeBase,RangeByMinutes,RangeByMinutesBase,RangeDaily,RangeDailyBase,RangeHourly,RangeHourlyBase,Task,TestNotificationsTask,WrapperTask,batch_email,core,email,execution_summary,retcode,scheduler,sendgrid,smtp,worker
```

Comment: Your `Test` class is not extending from `luigi.Task`. Also you have a typo in your `requires()` method (`class1` should be capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in directory with your script:

`python scrptfilenape.py Task --scheduler-host localhost`

Comment: yes, I have the same problem and *this* works. The question is why?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are placed like

```
./test/__init__.py
./test/test.py
```

Then you need to run

```
luigi -m test.test Test --local-scheduler
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import luigi
class Test: 

    def requires(self):
        return class1(param1='path', param2='', param3=123)

    def run(self):
        # some logic with using those 3 params

    def output(self):
        pass

class Class1(luigi.Task):

    param1 = luigi.Parameter()
    fileparam = file
    param2 = luigi.Parameter(default=fileparam)
    param3 = luigi.Parameter(default=123)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

suppose you save this as sample.py.
you can run this as python -m  sample Class1 --local-scheduler

Class1 will be the main or wrapper task which calls other tasks.